# Probability question from GRE subject test

Tags: probability, advice

I ran across the following problem while practicing for the GRE math subject test:

Suppose $X$ is a discrete random variable on the set of positive integers such that for each positive integer $n$, the probability that $X = n $ is $\frac{1}{2^n}$. If $Y$ is a random variable with the same probability distribution and $X$ and $Y$ are independent, what is the probability that the value of at least one of the variables $X$ and $Y$ is greater than $3$?

In trying to solve this, I tried the following:

We want $P(X>3 \wedge Y>3) = 2P(X>3) = 2\sum_{i=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i} = \frac{1}{4}$. However, the correct answer is $\frac{15}{64}$ and I understand the reasoning for this answer, but why is mine incorrect? Where did I go wrong? Is it because I forgot to take into account the possibility that $X$ and $Y$ may not be disjoint (i.e. I am double counting), which seems possible since $\frac{15}{64}<\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: One can write $\Pr(X>3 \wedge Y>3)$ or $\Pr(X>3)\Pr(Y>3)$ but it makes no sense to write $\Pr(X>3)\wedge\Pr(Y>3)$.  Those probabilities are _numbers_.  The "$\wedge$" operation is not applied to numbers. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I was simply typing quickly and made the error. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find $P(X > 3\: \text{or}\: Y > 3)$, which is the same as $1 - P(X \le 3\: \text{and}\: Y \le 3)$. Since $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution and are independent, $P(X \le 3\: \text{and}\: Y \le 3) = P(X \le 3)P(Y\le 3) = P(X \le 3)^2$. So you compute

$$1 - P(X \le 3)^2 = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}\right)^2 = 1 - \left(\frac{7}{8}\right)^2 = \frac{15}{64}.$$

The problem in your solution is the first step: $P(X > 3\: \text{or}\: Y > 3) \neq 2P(X > 3)$. Recall the rule $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. My question is what is wrong with what I did? Is it simply the wrong approach to this problem or is it because of what I mentioned above?

Comment: @Kevin Your first step is wrong. Recall $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: I see... so it's because I was double counting. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin glad to be of help.